# Extra column appears when appending selected row from one csv to another in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I have this code which appends a column of a csv file as a row to another csv file:

```
def append_pandas(s,d):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=';', header=None)
    df_t = df.T
    df_t.iloc[0:1, 0:1] = 'Time Point'
    df_t.at[1, 0] = 1
    df_t.columns = df_t.iloc[0]
    df_new = df_t.drop(0)
    pdb = pd.read_csv(d, sep=';')
    newpd = pdb.append(df_new)
    from pandas import DataFrame
    newpd.to_csv(d, sep=';')
```

The result is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Instead, every time the row is appended, there is an extra "Unnamed" column appearing on the left:

[image]

Do you know how to fix that?..
Please, help :(

My csv documents from which I select a column look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `index=False` to your `to_csv()` method

Comment: It worked! So simple haha. There is something else which I am trying to do. There is this column "Time Point". I want it to increase by one every time the row is concatenated. So that a resulting column is '1', '2', '3' etc. Do you have any ideas of how to do it in this function?

Comment: I advise you to create another question. I'm not sure to understand correctly, but does `df['Time Point'] = df['Time Point'] +1` do the job ?

Comment: Not really.. It says 'key error Time Point'. No worries, I have just created another question :)